# Android: How to prevent app crash when sending something via bluetooth while not connected?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Edit: turns out it doesn't throw an IOException, but a NullPointerException (because the outputStream is null). Catching it works just fine when trying to write from the outputStream.

However when trying to read from the inputStream for some reason catching the NullPointerException didn't work, so I just added a check `if (inStream !=null)` before calling the method that reads from the inputStream.

So well, I solved the problem.

---

So, I have an app which among other things connects to a device via bluetooth and can send/recieve strings.

However it can happen that the connection fails, either because the paired device is turned off or because the device didn't pick the connection. In this case, when I try to send a string, my app crashes.

How do I prevent this crash, and instead display a toast and try to reconnect? Surrounding with an IOException doesn't do anything.

Possibly helpful code:

Method to initiate the connection:

```
private void init() throws IOException {


    if (blueAdapter != null) {
        if (blueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = blueAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            if(bondedDevices.size() > 0){
                BluetoothDevice bt2 = null;
                for(BluetoothDevice bt : bondedDevices) {
                    bt2 = bt;
                }


                BluetoothDevice device = bt2;
                ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
                BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
                socket.connect();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                inStream = socket.getInputStream();
            }

            Log.e("error", "No appropriate paired devices.");
        }else{
            Log.e("error", "Bluetooth is disabled.");
        }
    }
}
```

Method to write the string:

```
public void write(String s) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
}
```

Code that writes the string:

```
try {
    write(string);
} catch (IOException e1) {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Couldn't send the code.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Edit: I tried to add a check in the init method:

```
if (!socket.isConnected()) {
    toast("Couldn't connect. Reconnecting...");
    init();}
```

However it doesn't work, the toast doesn't display and it times out anyway (doesn't loop forever like it'd do if there's no connection available).

Comment: What is the purpose of defining three different Bluetooth device references? Also could you add the logcat of your error to your question?

Comment: I don't know, I just copy/pasted code from https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/simple-android-to-arduino-via-bluetooth-part-3/, mixed with code I found in a few other places. However it works just fine so I don't think it's that. As for the logcat I don't have it, ADB doesn't recognize my device and the emulator is too laggy.

Comment: If adb doesn't recognize your device, how do you run the app?

Comment: I manually transfer the apk to the phone, then run it via a file explorer

Comment: Sounds like you just need to enable usb debugging on your phone

Comment: Nope, it is enabled. It's just that the drivers aren't installed, and the drivers I've tested don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your socket.connect() connect with

```
while(true){
   try {
       socket.connect();
       //When we are here the connection suceeded
   }catch (Exception e){  
       //The connection failed
   }
}
```

However be careful to not run this on the UI Thread as this will block the thread and make your app unresponsive. Rather create a Searcher Thread which then calls back that it found something.

You don't need the line

```
BluetoothDevice device = bt2;
```

just replace device with bt2 in your code and delete that line.
Please also note that your loop

```
for(BluetoothDevice bt : bondedDevices) {
    bt2 = bt;
}
```

will always give you the last item, which could lead to the problem of you searching for a completely different Item that you want.